# Fetch max value in a list of objects which are inside list of objects by month using Java Stream

Tags: java, java-stream

I have list of Store objects and each Store object has a list of Sales objects. I want to fetch the Store object which has the highest sale for any item for a particular month.

```
public class Store {
 private String storeName;
 private String contactInfo;
 private List<Sales> sales;

//getter & setter
}
public class Sales {
 private String month;
 private String year;
 private BigInteger price;

//getter & setter
}
```

As of now I'm able to filter the list of Store objects by month

```
List<Store> stores = list.stream()
             .filter(s -> s.getPrice().stream().anyMatch(t -> t.getMonth().contains("Jan")))
             .collect(Collections.toList());
```

But I want to filter this list further to get a single store object which has the max price for the month of January.

EDIT :
sample list structure in JSON format

```
[
   {
      "storeName": "abc",
      "contactInfo": "xcb",
      "sales": [{
                  "month" : "Jan",
                  "year": "2022",
                  "price": 3000
                },
                {
                  "month" : "Feb",
                  "year": "2022",
                  "price": 3300
                }
               ]
   },
   {
      "storeName": "abcde",
      "contactInfo": "xcbe",
      "sales": [{
                  "month" : "Jan",
                  "year": "2022",
                  "price": 2000
                },
                {
                  "month" : "Feb",
                  "year": "2022",
                  "price": 4000
                }
               ]
   }
]
```

Thank you!

Comment: What does the `price` field contain? a floating point? an integer? Because if you use some kind of numeric type you could make use of the `Stream.max()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can flat map to pairs of (store, price) and select the max:

```
stores.stream()
        .flatMap(store -> store.getSales()
                .stream()
                .filter(sales -> sales.getMonth().contains("Jan"))
                .map(sales -> Map.entry(store, sales.getPrice())))
        .max(Entry.comparingByValue())
        .map(Entry::getKey)
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I would advise to use appropriate data types:

- `BigDecimal` for price instead of `String`.
- [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/YearMonth.html) from `java.time` package instead of two `String` fields.

```
public class Sales {
    private YearMonth yearMonth;
    private BigDecimal price;
    
    // getters
}
```

The method responsible for finding the `Store` having the highest price for a particular `YearMonth` might be implemented like that:

```
public static Store getMostExpensiveStoreByMonth(List<Store> stores,
                                                 YearMonth yearMonth) {
    
    return stores.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy( // intermediate map Map<Store, Optional<BigDecimal>>
            Function.identity(),
            Collectors.flatMapping(store -> store.getSales().stream()
                    .filter(sales -> sales.getYearMonth().equals(yearMonth))
                    .map(Sales::getPrice),
                Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.naturalOrder()))
        ))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .filter(entry -> entry.getValue().isPresent()) // Optional would be empty if there was no sales during the given month in a particular store
        .max(Comparator.comparing((Map.Entry<Store, Optional<BigDecimal>> entry) -> entry.getValue().get()))
        .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
        .orElseThrow();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data source is a JSON string, it can be done by a JSON query language such as Josson directly.

https://github.com/octomix/josson

```
Josson josson = Josson.fromJsonString(
        "[" +
        "   {" +
        "      \"storeName\": \"abc\"," +
        "      \"contactInfo\": \"xcb\"," +
        "      \"sales\": [{" +
        "                  \"month\" : \"Jan\"," +
        "                  \"year\": \"2022\"," +
        "                  \"price\": 3000" +
        "                }," +
        "                {" +
        "                  \"month\" : \"Feb\"," +
        "                  \"year\": \"2022\"," +
        "                  \"price\": 3300" +
        "                }" +
        "               ]" +
        "   }," +
        "   {" +
        "      \"storeName\": \"abcde\"," +
        "      \"contactInfo\": \"xcbe\"," +
        "      \"sales\": [{" +
        "                  \"month\" : \"Jan\"," +
        "                  \"year\": \"2022\"," +
        "                  \"price\": 2000" +
        "                }," +
        "                {" +
        "                  \"month\" : \"Feb\"," +
        "                  \"year\": \"2022\"," +
        "                  \"price\": 4000" +
        "                }" +
        "               ]" +
        "   }" +
        "] ");
JsonNode node = josson.getNode("findByMax(sales[month='Jan'].price)");
System.out.println(node.toPrettyString());
```

Output

```
{
  "storeName" : "abc",
  "contactInfo" : "xcb",
  "sales" : [ {
    "month" : "Jan",
    "year" : "2022",
    "price" : 3000
  }, {
    "month" : "Feb",
    "year" : "2022",
    "price" : 3300
  } ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you find a good comparator, then we don't need intermediate flatmap operations:

```
return stores.stream().max(Comparator.comparing(
       store -> store.getSales().stream()
                     .findFirst(sales -> sales.getMonth().contains("Jan"))
                     .map(sales -> sales.getPrice())
                     .orElse(0)
));
```

This assumes the sales are already grouped, i.e. the sales price is the total per month.

If the sales are individual, you could do this by a nested max call:

```
return stores.stream().max(Comparator.comparing(
       store -> store.getSales().stream()
                     .filter(sales -> sales.getMonth().contains("Jan"))
                     .max(Comparator.comparing(Sales::getPrice)
                     .orElse(0)
));
```

However, this has the downside that the value is not calculated once per store, but everytime two stores need to be compared, which is O(N * log N) instead of N.

IIUC if you use the flatmap operation, the values that are being compared are only calculated once.

Comment: That's a very inefficient comparator. And you're assuming there's no more than 1 sales sales item per month.

Comment: Inefficient because the result of the comparing is not cached, you mean? You have a point, it would do the mapping O(N *  log N) instead of O(N) times.

And I did assume the Sales was already a total per month, but that's indeed not what OP asked.